# I want to fix this table in the middle of the paper. I tried centering and those things but it didn't work

Tags: tables

```
\begin{tabular}{||c||c||c||c||c||} \hline
\textbf{n} &  $\boldsymbol{s_n}$ & $\boldsymbol{t_n}$ & $\boldsymbol{s_{n+1}-s_n}$ & $\boldsymbol{t_{n+1}-t_n}$  \\ \hline \hline
0& 0& 0& 0.166666666666667 & 0.166666666666667 \\ \hline
1& 0.16666666666666 & 0.166666666666667 & 0.0714285714285714& 0.0833333333333333 \\ \hline
2 & 0.238095238095238 & 0.25 & 0.0189075630252101 & 0.0416666666666666  \\ \hline
3 & 0.257002801120448 & 0.291666666666667 & 0.00150001234578062 & 0.0208333333333332 \\ \hline
4 & 0.258502813466229 & 0.3125 & 9.54098279665194e-06 & 0.0104166666666664 \\ \hline
5 & 0.258512354449025 & 0.322916666666666 & 3.86028153886997e-10 & 0.00520833333333282 \\ \hline
6 & 0.258512354835054 & 0.328124999999999 & 0 & 0.00260416666666563 \\ \hline
7 & 0.258512354835054 & 0.330729166666665 & 0 & 0.00130208333333126 \\ \hline
8 & 0.258512354835054 & 0.332031249999996 & 0 & 0.000651041666662522 \\ \hline
9 & 0.258512354835054 & 0.332682291666658 & 0 & 0.000325520833325044 \\ \hline
10 & 0.258512354835054 & 0.333007812499983 & 0 & 0.000162760416650087 \\ \hline
11 & 0.258512354835054 & 0.333170572916633 & 0 & 8.13802083001747e-05 \\ \hline
12 & 0.258512354835054 & 0.333251953124934 & 0 & 4.06901041003493e-05 \\ \hline
13 & 0.258512354835054 & 0.333292643229034 & 0 & 2.03450519506987e-05 \\ \hline
14 & 0.258512354835054 & 0.333312988280985 & 0 & 1.01725257763974e-05 \\ \hline
15 & 0.258512354835054 & 0.333323160806761 & 0 & 5.08626249029476e-06 \\ \hline
16 & 0.258512354835054 & 0.333328247069251 & 0 & 2.54313044933951e-06 \\ \hline
17 & 0.258512354835054 & 0.333330790199701 & 0 & 1.27156363305403e-06 \\ \hline
18 & 0.258512354835054 & 0.333332061763334 & 0 & 6.35778633295558e-07 \\ \hline
19 & 0.258512354835054 & 0.333332697541967 & 0 & 3.17882950295889e-07 \\ \hline
20 & 0.258512354835054 & 0.333333015424917 & 0 & 1.58928743332343e-07 \\ \hline
21 & 0.258512354835054 & 0.333333174353661 & 0 & 7.94389151681507e-08 \\ \hline
22 & 0.258512354835054 & 0.333333253792576 & 0 & 3.96686016257419e-08 \\ \hline
23 & 0.258512354835054 & 0.333333293461178 & 0 & 1.97330433104881e-08 \\ \hline
24 & 0.258512354835054 & 0.333333313194221 & 0 & 9.66758090248376e-09 \\ \hline
25 & 0.258512354835054 & 0.333333322861802 & 0 & 4.46267672815637e-09 \\ \hline
26 & 0.258512354835054 & 0.333333327324478 & 0 & 1.65717795042042e-09 \\ \hline
27 & 0.258512354835054 & 0.333333328981656 & 0 & 3.15537984629799e-10 \\ \hline
28 & 0.258512354835054 & 0.333333329297194 & 0 & 1.23340782032244e-11 \\ \hline
29 & 0.258512354835054 & 0.333333329309528 & 0 & 1.89293025698589e-14 \\ \hline
\end{tabular} \\ \\
```

[image: Need to be corrected, should be properly alligned]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable  document that shows the problem.

Comment: your image shows that the table is simply wider than the text block so can not be centred. Do you _need_ to display that many decimal places? If you do, and you want that table layout you would need `\footnotesize` or `\tiny` or some such font to make it fit (but it will be unreadably small)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a big table should go in a float with a caption briefly explaining the table, so you can refer to it in the text as “Table~`<number>`” with the `\label`-`\ref` mechanism.

Trying to set it “in place” will almost invariably result in bad pagination.

I get a decent result with `\footnotesize` in the standard text width for A4 paper; it would probably improve with more generous width.

I suggest avoiding vertical rules that are ugly and take up space. For numeric tables, `siunitx` is recommended.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}

\begin{document}

We can see the values in Table~\ref{bigtable}.

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\sisetup{
  group-digits=false,
  output-exponent-marker = \text{e},
}

\caption{Add here a caption\label{bigtable}}

\footnotesize
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
 @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
 c
 S[table-format=1.15]
 S[table-format=1.15]
 S[table-format=1.14e-2]
 @{\hspace{-10pt}}
 S[table-format=1.14e-2]
 @{\hspace{-10pt}}
}
\toprule
$n$ &  {$s_n$} & {$t_n$} & {$s_{n+1}-s_n$} & {$t_{n+1}-t_n$} \\
\midrule
0& 0& 0& 0.166666666666667 & 0.166666666666667 \\
1& 0.16666666666666 & 0.166666666666667 & 0.0714285714285714& 0.0833333333333333 \\
2 & 0.238095238095238 & 0.25 & 0.0189075630252101 & 0.0416666666666666  \\
3 & 0.257002801120448 & 0.291666666666667 & 0.00150001234578062 & 0.0208333333333332 \\
4 & 0.258502813466229 & 0.3125 & 9.54098279665194e-06 & 0.0104166666666664 \\
5 & 0.258512354449025 & 0.322916666666666 & 3.86028153886997e-10 & 0.00520833333333282 \\
6 & 0.258512354835054 & 0.328124999999999 & 0 & 0.00260416666666563 \\
7 & 0.258512354835054 & 0.330729166666665 & 0 & 0.00130208333333126 \\
8 & 0.258512354835054 & 0.332031249999996 & 0 & 0.000651041666662522 \\
9 & 0.258512354835054 & 0.332682291666658 & 0 & 0.000325520833325044 \\
10 & 0.258512354835054 & 0.333007812499983 & 0 & 0.000162760416650087 \\
11 & 0.258512354835054 & 0.333170572916633 & 0 & 8.13802083001747e-05 \\
12 & 0.258512354835054 & 0.333251953124934 & 0 & 4.06901041003493e-05 \\
13 & 0.258512354835054 & 0.333292643229034 & 0 & 2.03450519506987e-05 \\
14 & 0.258512354835054 & 0.333312988280985 & 0 & 1.01725257763974e-05 \\
15 & 0.258512354835054 & 0.333323160806761 & 0 & 5.08626249029476e-06 \\
16 & 0.258512354835054 & 0.333328247069251 & 0 & 2.54313044933951e-06 \\
17 & 0.258512354835054 & 0.333330790199701 & 0 & 1.27156363305403e-06 \\
18 & 0.258512354835054 & 0.333332061763334 & 0 & 6.35778633295558e-07 \\
19 & 0.258512354835054 & 0.333332697541967 & 0 & 3.17882950295889e-07 \\
20 & 0.258512354835054 & 0.333333015424917 & 0 & 1.58928743332343e-07 \\
21 & 0.258512354835054 & 0.333333174353661 & 0 & 7.94389151681507e-08 \\
22 & 0.258512354835054 & 0.333333253792576 & 0 & 3.96686016257419e-08 \\
23 & 0.258512354835054 & 0.333333293461178 & 0 & 1.97330433104881e-08 \\
24 & 0.258512354835054 & 0.333333313194221 & 0 & 9.66758090248376e-09 \\
25 & 0.258512354835054 & 0.333333322861802 & 0 & 4.46267672815637e-09 \\
26 & 0.258512354835054 & 0.333333327324478 & 0 & 1.65717795042042e-09 \\
27 & 0.258512354835054 & 0.333333328981656 & 0 & 3.15537984629799e-10 \\
28 & 0.258512354835054 & 0.333333329297194 & 0 & 1.23340782032244e-11 \\
29 & 0.258512354835054 & 0.333333329309528 & 0 & 1.89293025698589e-14 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is possible to add vertical lines in this code ? My advisor want the vertical lines as well, and might be aligning to the right ? It would be perfect